# Help me understand this Perl statement with <<'ESQ'

Tags: perl, heredoc

```
substr($obj_strptime,index($strptime,"sub")+6,0) = <<'ESQ';
 shift; # package
 ....
 ....
ESQ
```

What is this ESQ and what is it doing here? Please help me understand these statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It marks the end of a [here-doc section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3C_EOF_).

EOF is more traditional than ESQ though.

Comment: I commonly see many variations matching `/^EO[A-Z]+$/`, End Of File and End Of Data, do seem most common, but it's also nice to provide a bit more help as to what it is that your ending.

Comment: I like `END` or `END_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` where `_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` is something descriptive of the content.  For example, `END_HTML` if I have an html fragment or `END_ICON` if I am embedding an encoded icon in a gui.

Comment: Also note that the here-doc is assigned to the indicated position (index($strptime,"sub")+6) in $obj_strptime.

Answer (score 1):

This construct is known as a here-doc (because you're getting standard input from a document *here* rather than an external document on the file system somewhere).

It basically reads everything from the next line up to but excluding an end marker line, and uses that as standard input to the program or command that you're running. The end marker line is controlled by the text following the `<<`.

As an example, in `bash` (which I'm more familiar with than Perl), the command:

```
cat <<EOF
hello
goodbye
EOF
```

will run `cat` and then send two lines to its standard input (the hello and goodbye lines). Perl also has this feature though the syntax is slightly different (as you would expect, given it's a different language). Still, it's close enough for the explanation to still hold.

Wikipedia has [an entry for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) which you probably would have found had you known it was called a here-doc, but otherwise it would be rather hard to figure it out.

You can basically use any suitable marker. For example, if one of your input lines was `EOF`, you couldn't really use that as a marker since the standard input would be terminated prematurely:

```
cat <<EOF
This section contains the line ...
EOF
but then has more stuff
and this line following is the real ...
EOF
```

In that case, you could use `DONE` (or anything else that doesn't appear in the text on its own line).

There are other options such as using quotes around the marker (so the indentation can look better) and the use of single or double quotes to control variable substitution.

If you go to the [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) page and search for `<<EOF`, it will hopefully all become clear.